# Solving Gram-Schmidt with a matrix that is not completly linear independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I have the matrix $A = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&1&7\\ 2&1&8\\ 3&1&9 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$.  I see that the 2nd column times 6 added with the 1st gives you the 3rd column, so the columns of the matrix do not form a linearly independent set of vectors.

Now, on the the Gram Schmidt. I get $u_1 = A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$. This would mean that
$$
e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I then get $u_2 = a_2 - (a_2 \cdot e_1 )e_1$. I then get $u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{6}{\sqrt{14}} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{2}{\sqrt{14}} \\ \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}} \end{bmatrix}$. This gives me $u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{4}{7} \\ \frac{1}{7} \\ \frac{-2}{7} \end{bmatrix}$. So my
$$
e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{4\sqrt{21}}{21} \\ \frac{\sqrt{21}}{21} \\ \frac{-2\sqrt{21}}{21}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now this is where things got interesting. $u_3 = a_3 - (a_3 \cdot e_1 )e_1 - (a_3 \cdot e_2 )e_2$. This gives me
$$
u_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{50}{14} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} - \frac{6}{7} \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
which I don't think is possible since $Q$ needs to be full rank, I believe? Also, $R$ is allowed to have zeroes in the diagonal. I plugged the original matrix into Matlab and got the first two rows right, but the third won't come out correct. I have redone it about $3$ times to check the math and have reduced in different ways each time giving me the same answer.

Comment: That's odd matlab says the third row would not be 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original matrix has rank $2$, which means that the columns span a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$.  The Gram—Schmidt process replaces your vectors, one at a time, by an orthonormal set.  This means that each new vector $e_k$ is

- orthogonal to the entire subspace spanned by $e_1, \ldots, e_{k-1}$ and
- has unit length.

In particular, it doesn't change the rank!  So, the first two vectors you found give you  a shiny, new *orthonormal* basis $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ for the column space of the matrix.  The third vector, having a linear dependence with the first two, is necessarily in the span of those two vectors.

So, in the G—S process, when you subtract off the components of the third vector that lie parallel to each of $e_1$ and $e_2$, you get rid of everything!  (Your calculation confirms this.)  There is no third orthogonal direction.

Comment: See, that is what I thought, but matlab kept telling me it was wrong. I guess that's what I get for not checking with other tools like my calculator. I just plugged in the matrix I got originally and out came the right answers. Thanks for the detailed explanation, makes a lot of sense!

Comment: The G—S algorithm may be implemented in matlab in such a way that it always returns a full list of vectors (three in your case).  Although you can make the third vector have unit length, there's no way to make it orthogonal to the others.  So, I have no idea what the software is doing.

Comment: We can make sure G-S give full list of orthogonal unit vectors. Just make up one unit vector in the orthogonal direction of the first two unit vectors. Then the QR decomposition of the original matrix would give the third diagonal entry zero.

Comment: Also, since we are working on R^3, the third unit vector can be obtained by the cross product of e1 and e2.